# Colorbox stop background scroll and return to same location on parent page

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, scroll, colorbox

I have an unordered list that I've created in drupal 7 using views. Each list item has a link that opens a colorbox. If you put the mouse on the faded background of the colorbox (which is the parent page) you can scroll the parent page. What I'm after is the parent page to stop scrolling and return to the same position/anchor on parent page when its closed.

Searching through questions on here I found the code:

```
$(document).bind('cbox_open', function () {
    $('html').css({ overflow: 'hidden' });
}).bind('cbox_closed', function () {
    $('html').css({ overflow: 'auto' });
});
```

The code above works but puts the parent page scroll back to the very top.

This would work if I could do it dynamically;

```
$("html,body").scrollTop(400); // 300 is just a example
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get your question and what you mean by "stop background scrolling". Maybe you can set up a jsfiddle? All in all it sounds like a messed up user experience..

Comment: I've updated the post Kannix, hopefully that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
var position;
$(document).bind('cbox_open', function() {
    position = $("html,body").scrollTop();
    $('html').css({
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });
}).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
    $('html').css({
        overflow: 'auto'
    });
    $("html,body").scrollTop(position);
});​
```

Comment: This is a good solution, it does work. Is there a way to stop it jumping down the page once you close the colorbox. I think due to putting overflow hidden in the css it gets rid of the scrollbars and moves everything to the top. It just looks a little bit buggy when you close the colorbox then it jumps down the page - does that make sense?

Comment: I don't understand why you set the overflow like that... When the overflow of the BODY is hidden, the colorbox popup cannot be scrolled (if it's longer than the visible area)!

Comment: Further more, for me this does not solve the problem I was looking for an answer to (when changing the height of the content and/or the entire colorbox, the page scrolls to the top automatically). First of all, playing with the overflow of the page prevents from scrolling the colorbox (like I mentioned in my previous comment here), AND on the "open" handler, I get 0 for the current position of the scroll.

Answer (score 17):

kannix got it.  I'd just hide the overflow on the body, the html's overflow is probably fine.

```
$(document).bind('cbox_open', function() {
    $('body').css({ overflow: 'hidden' });
}).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
    $('body').css({ overflow: '' });
});​
```

However, it shouldn't be scrolling back to the top.  Setting the scrolltop is just papering over another problem (such as not canceling the default action on an a clicked anchor element).

Comment: Jack, completely missed this comment. I've combined the two and it works. Using the var position; and removing the html class and just kept body it now works.

Comment: This completely resolved the issue for me. I think the scrollTop solution is a hack.

Answer (score 1):

I have two optimizations to suggest:

1. The best approach would be to add an remove a css-class. If you do so, you could be sure, that everything got kind of "reset" after you leave.
2. if you use cbox_cleanup in favor of cbox_closed, user will hardly notice the 'jumping' of the content.

Therefore my solution would be:

```js
$(document).bind('cbox_open', function() {
  $('html').addClass("noScrollSimple");
}).bind('cbox_cleanup', function() {
  $('html').removeClass("noScrollSimple");
});
```

```css
.noScrollSimple {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For iphone/ipad I have this solution that works great!

```
$(document).bind('cbox_open', function() {
    var position = $('body').scrollTop();
        $('body').attr("data-position", position);
        $('body').css({position : 'fixed', top: '-' + position + 'px'});
    }).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
        $('body').css({position : 'relative', top: '0'}); 
        var position = $('body').attr("data-position");
        $('body').scrollTop(position);
    });
```